# Math formulas from option values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help me with this solution. I have simple form:

```
<select id="select-1" name="select-1">
<option value="0"> option 1</option>
<option value="1"> option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="select-2" name="select-2">
<option value="1"> option 1</option>
<option value="2"> option 2</option>
<option value="3"> option 3</option>
</select>
```

Below this form i want display dynamically calculation like this:

option from select-1 is in array (e.g. value[0]=1.50, value[1]=5)

option from select-2 is option value from list

In start result: value[0]=1.50 * 1 = 1,50

after change select result will change dynamically.

Angular is neccessary or only JS?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value of each option of your select-2 with a "on-change event" on select-1.

In your on-change function you have to get the value of the select-1 and set the different values for your select-2.